# Image gamma correction in qt

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing

I try  to change the gamma of an image using qt but i don't get the desirable result .
Here is my code :

```
QImage Filters::aply_filtre_gamma(QImage image){
   // (std::pow((image.pixel(x,y)/255),2.2))*255
    QRgb val;

    for(int x=1; x < image.width(); x++)
        for(int y=1 ; y < image.height(); y++){
           val=image.pixel(x,y);
           val=qRed(val);

           val=std::pow(val/255,2)*255;
           //std::cout<<"valoare pixel:"<<valll<<std::endl;
           image.setPixel(x,y, QColor(val, val, val).rgb());
          // image.setPixel(x,y,std::pow((valll/65025),2.2)*65025);

        }

return image ;
}
```

Is there an error in my code or i don't use the formula correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there happens some type mismatch. (I didn't check but I would wonder if it even compiles.)

[`QImage::pixel()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#pixel) returns [`QRgb`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#QRgb-typedef).

[`qRed()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#qRed) takes an `QRgb` and returns an `int`.

Hence, I wonder what `val=qRed(val);` would do. (If it compiles it doesn't probably do the expected.)

This in mind, I changed OP's code a bit:

```
QImage Filters::aply_filtre_gamma(QImage image)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < image.width(); ++x)
        for(int y = 0 ; y < image.height(); ++y) {
           const QRgb rgb = image.pixel(x, y);
           const double r = qRed(rgb) / 255.0;
           const double g = qGreen(rgb) / 255.0;
           const double b = qBlue(rgb) / 255.0;
           image.setPixelColor(x, y,
             QColor(
               255 * std::pow(r, 2.2),
               255 * std::pow(g, 2.2),
               255 * std::pow(b, 2.2)));
        }
    return image;
}
```

Before, I took a short refresh in Wikipedia concerning [gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction).

**Note:**

I fixed also the start values of `for` loops. The pixel of upper left corner has coordinates (0, 0) – but not (1, 1).

---

A complete test/example – `testQImageGamma.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

QPixmap fromImage(const QImage &qImg)
{
  QPixmap qPixmap;
  qPixmap.convertFromImage(qImg);
  return qPixmap;
}

QImage gamma(const QImage &qImg, double exp)
{
  QImage qImgRet(qImg);
  for (int x = 0; x < qImg.width(); ++x) {
    for (int y = 0 ; y < qImg.height(); ++y) {
      const QRgb rgb = qImg.pixel(x, y);
      const double r = qRed(rgb) / 255.0;
      const double g = qGreen(rgb) / 255.0;
      const double b = qBlue(rgb) / 255.0;
      qImgRet.setPixelColor(x, y,
        QColor(
          255 * std::pow(r, exp),
          255 * std::pow(g, exp),
          255 * std::pow(b, exp)));
    }
  }
  return qImgRet;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup data
  const QImage qImg("cat.rgb.png");
  const QImage qImgGamma = gamma(qImg, 1 / 2.2);
  // setup UI
  QWidget qWin;
  qWin.setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("Gamma Correction"));
  QVBoxLayout qVBox;
  QLabel qLbl(QString::fromUtf8("Original Image:"));
  qVBox.addWidget(&qLbl);
  QLabel qLblImg;
  qLblImg.setPixmap(fromImage(qImg));
  qVBox.addWidget(&qLblImg);
  qWin.setLayout(&qVBox);
  QLabel qLblGamma(QString::fromUtf8("Gamma corrected Image:"));
  qVBox.addWidget(&qLblGamma);
  QLabel qLblImgGamma;
  qLblImgGamma.setPixmap(fromImage(qImgGamma));
  qVBox.addWidget(&qLblImgGamma);
  qWin.setLayout(&qVBox);
  qWin.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

The Qt project file `testQImageGamma.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQImageGamma.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiled and tested on [cygwin64](http://cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQImageGamma.pro

$ make && ./testQImageGamma
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

[image: Snapshot of testQImageGamma]

Please, note that I used `1 / 2.2` as exponent in my example. (With 2.2 the gamma corrected image became darker.)

Comment: @SilviuPetrut I made an MCVE, and thereby fixed some small bugs in my first code attempt.

Comment: @SilviuPetrut, you may now upvote the answer as well.